# Bash Operators: Squaring a previously calculated variable, then storing it in a new variable

Tags: bash, variables, store, operator-keyword, exponent

I'm using bash to write a script for FSL, an imaging software. It's all through command line though, so it's straightforward to script.

I'm struggling to be able to square my previously calculated variable, and then store it as a new variable:

```
varStdBase=$(fslstats ${varBase%.nii.gz}_MAX100.nii.gz -S)
echo "Std Dev. is: "$varStdBase

varS1=$(echo '$varStdBase^2'|bc)
echo "variance is: "$varS1
```

It's getting varS1 that I'm struggling with. I keep getting the error message:

```
syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".886438")
```

I've also tried:

```
varS1=$(($varStdBase**2))
```

and:

```
let varS1=$varStdBase**2
```

also:

```
varS1=$(echo $(($varStdBase**2)))
```

And more, all to no avail...

I'm struggling hard with trying to figure out the syntax that bash is wanting to do this simple task.

Thanks!

Comment: Put `set -x` at top of script so you can see how bash is doing variable substitution.

Comment: Thanks! This help a lot with trouble shooting

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
echo '$varStdBase^2'|bc
```

gives an error since the single quotes don't allow a variable value to be expanded. However using double quotes *will*:

```
echo "$varStdBase^2"|bc
```

e.g.

```
$ a=123
$ echo "$a^2"|bc
15129
```

(the error message *syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".886438")* is coming from the bc executable, note)

Comment: AH! Yes that worked. 
Thanks so much for the speedy response!